# jsoncpp insert object into document rather than append

Tags: jsoncpp

We are working with a partner that requires some fields to appear at the beginning of a JSON document.  We build a document before knowing what this initial data will be and have been unable to find a way to insert it at the beginning.
We have:

```
Json::Value json_message
json_message["singlestring"] = "blah blah blah"
```

then later a function gets this message

```
SomeFunction(Json::Value &json_message) {
   Json::Value sub_json;
   sub_json["one"] = "some sub 1";
   sub_json["two"] = "some sub 2";
   json_message["subobject"] = sub_json;
}
```

which results in

```
{
"singlestring":"blah blah blah",
"subobject":
{
"one":"some sub 1",
"two":"some sub 2",
}
}
```

but we need

```
{
"subobject":
{
"one":"some sub 1",
"two":"some sub 2",
},
"singlestring":"blah blah blah"
}
```

Is there a way to insert "subobject" to the beginning of the document, or to append the existing json_message to sub_json?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible due to the internal representation of object members.

JsonCpp uses a `std::map`. When you serialize to string using `FastWriter`, if an object is found `std::vector<JSONCPP_STRING> getMemberNames()` is called, which puts in a vector the keys of the `std::map`.

To reach your goal you must modify `getMemberNames()`, assigning a "priority" to members of your liking (such as `subobject`).

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspisions.